# Should I just use the xml parser or should I parse the xml file in a vector?

Tags: c++, xml, vector

I want to read GPS coordinates from a xml file into my program.

At the moment I use hard coded arrays to work with track points, but now I would like to make my program more dynamic, meaning I want to read the coordinates from a xml file.

Now my question is what is better: to use a xml parser (pugixml) to access the data directly from the file each time I need it, or to parse all the data into vectors using pugixml and hand the vector to the calculating class?

I have a class `FindPosition` which does calculations based on the coordinates and a class `XMLParser` which should get my data. It is possible that I have up to 100 track points or more in the xml file and my program needs to work in real time (GNSS data from outside comes in at update rate of 5Hz), so I would like to know which way is better for program flow and runtime.

Comment: Why not *both*? Use the XML parser to help read and extract the data you need, and put that data in a vector? And when you say "realtime" what do you mean by that? That you need to read this file once every second? Ten times per second? More? Less? For actual real-time gathering of data one would most likely not use files that need to be parsed and reparsed all over again each time, especially with a format which can require quite extensive processing to parse.

Comment: I guess I did not express well in my question, I mean to do both to get the vector. By realtime I mean that the user is running and the program needs an update rate of at least 5Hz.

Comment: Asking what's better without supplying a criteria for "better" is asking for opinions. This is strictly off-topic on SO.

Comment: Is the XML file fixed, or constantly updating?

Comment: 100 points is nothing.  Do whichever is easiest/clearest to start with until you think you have a performance problem.  If you had 100,0000 points then maybe you'd need to worry.

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't think I don't provide any criteria. I want to pass the data to another class and it needs to be fast. My imagination was that there is a standard way to do this which is clear to everyone that is used to working with xml files. Since I am new to this topic, it seemed like a sensible question.

Comment: @Martin the Xml file is fixed. So it is not like "good programming does not need the vector because pugixml provides all functions that you need in a reasonable time and using a vector would be an unneccessary workaround"?